# I am informed that "The system cannot find the path specified." once I open the Anaconda prompt

Tags: windows-10, anaconda

I just installed Anaconda on my Windows 10 computer recently. When I open the Anaconda prompt, it always informs me that "The system cannot find the path specified". Can anyone tell me what is wrong and how to fix it? Thanks.

(By the way, I have already added the path of Anaconda to the system environment variables, and the command, such as `python`, `conda --version` and `jupyter --version`, can work well.)

[image: Error - Screenshot]

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer (or your screenshot) by including the actual error message and the command causing it?

Comment: The error massage just appears on the first line of the screenshot -- "系统找不到指定的路径", which means "The system cannot find the path specified" in English. It appears just after I lauch Anaconda prompt every time, without my inputing any command.